# calling class function inside other class function c++

Tags: c++

My program is working fine and does what its supposed to do but the notation used doesn't seems right to me. I have a class with some variables and two functions:

foo.h

```
class foo{
private:
    int a;
public:
    void seta1(int value);
    void seta2(int value);
};
```

foo.cpp

```
void foo::seta2(int value)
{
     a = value;
}

void foo::seta1(int value)
{
    seta2(value);
}
```

then when i print variable a it has the value its supposed to have, but wouldn't this notation be more correct?

```
void foo::seta2(int value)
{
     this.a = value;
}
```

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the syntax and why?

Comment: `this.a` wouldn't compile, so it is already "less correct".

Comment: @MrEricSir i had wierd feeling it might be incorrect since i started to learn java.

Comment: The function `seta1` seems superfluous in this question.

Comment: @Beta it's simplified for better understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.   `this` is a pointer, not a reference.

`this->a = value` would be correct.

The `this->` is implied in this case (`a` a non-static member being accessed in a non-static member function).    There are some circumstances where the `this->` is required, but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

actually it should be `this->a`, since this is a pointer. however you don't need to usually write "this" since it's implied. both are correct.

This is only useful if a member variables is over-ridden by a local variable.

For example:

```
void foo::seta2(int a)
{
     this->a = a;
}
```